# How to get status of downloading?

Tags: android, download, download-manager

I use DownloadManager for getting status of downloading, but it still doesn't work, it never jumps to condition `if(c.moveToFirst())` and I don't know why. Could anybody help me, please?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action)) {

                DownloadManager downloadMgr = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL);
                Cursor c = downloadMgr.query(query);
                if(c==null) {
                    //
                }
                else {
                    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        int status = c.getInt(columnIndex);
                        if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING){
                        //do something
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Obviously your cursor is empty?

Comment: It seems that cursor is not empty, because it always go to else, not to if(c==null).

Comment: (null != empty).  I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but it just looks like nothing is being downloaded at the time of the query

Comment: I use this code in broadcastreceiver which is called when user turns his screen off, then it should call this code and tell me if user is downloading some data or not.

Comment: You are right, my cursor is really empty, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Adam : post your full code u are passing a file for downloading or want to get download folder stats

Comment: Look at edited question, I only need to get folder stats.

Comment: Then it must be @Adam that your query is wrong.

Comment: And how can I fix it? I have spent lots of time on this issue and I'd like to solve it.

Answer (score 9):

Here are few link refer it.

- [LINK1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)
- [LINK2](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/11/download-using-downloadmanager.html)

sample code is below::

```
DownloadManager.Query query = null;
    Cursor c = null;
    DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    query = new DownloadManager.Query();
     if(query!=null) {
                query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
            } else {
                return;
            }
    c = downloadManager.query(query);
    if(c.moveToFirst()) { 
    int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)); 
    switch(status) { 
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED: 
    break; 
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING: 
    break; 
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING: 
    break; 
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL: 
    break; 
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED: 
    break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: We are seeing some status codes of 0. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it

```
//broadcastReceiver
private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)

      
        //call notify off NotificationManager passing in the id & notification
        notificationManager.apply {

            notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification())
        }


        //DownloadManager.Query() is used to filter DownloadManager queries
        val query = DownloadManager.Query()

        query.setFilterById(id)

        val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
val status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))

            when (status) {
                DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL ->{


                }
                DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED -> {
                    
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```