# How to get download status and package name in android?

Tags: android, package, download-manager

Hi I am working with android.I want check weather an application is installed or not in the device.So How can I get the download status and package name if the user download an app in the device. Is it possible with download manager?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752247/1914223
By using the `PackageManager`, you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is for getting the package name...

```
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}
```

and for download status, you might want check this link...
[How to get status of downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258395/how-to-get-status-of-downloading)